# Remove the Offset by ffmpeg while generating images from Video

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -vf fps=1/15 -s 120x67 thumbs/movie_%04d.png
```

Hi i am trying to generate images from a video but the first image is generated form 00:07 so the first image at 00:00 is missing can anyone help me out.

Comment: I believe it is the expected behavior. `fps=1/15` means that you are keeping only 1 frame over 15 seconds. So, (sensibly?) FFmpeg is picking the middle frame, which is located around t=7.5, thus the starting time marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by setting the start interval as `-ss -00:00:07`.